# Dropping Server 2008 R2 SP1 Standard from Domain to Workgroup

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to drop one of our servers (Server 2008 R2 SP1) down to a Workgroup.  Currently, it is on the domain and it was our second backup that we no longer need.  I tried a few things that I saw online, and I am not having any luck.  I tried `sconfig` in the command prompt, but that did not do anything - just generated an error. I know it probably is because it is not server core, but I thought I would just do it for kicks.

I wanted to know if there was anyway instead of the normal workgroup droppage that I could do before I resorted to that way.  Also, once the server is on the workgroup is it okay to use this server elsewhere?  As in moving it to a different location and joining a different domain?

I already removed all the roles from the server so that part is done.  Please let me know if I need to do anything else because this is the first time I am actually dropping a server from the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on My Computer
Select Properties
Click on Change Settings under Computer Name, domain, and workgroup settings
Click Change on the Computer Name tab
Select Workgroup from the radio buttons and put in the name of the workgroup you want to use, click OK
Restart as prompted

And yes, it's fine to add this machine to another domain if you desire, assuming it's not infected/misconfigured etc but it's almost always better to format the disks & do a clean OS reload if you are not keeping any of the services currently on the box.

Comment: thank you so much.  We do the same procedure for dropping workstations from the domain to workgroup.  I just wanted to make sure that because this is a server that it did not require anything differently.

so you would suggest that we format the hard drive and install a clean version of Server 2008 R2 SP1?

thanks!

Comment: Yes. Just to be clear - this is NOT a Domain Controller, correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct.  This is not a domain controller.  This server will be a secondary server at our other location.  We just would hate to waste the time that we invested with Windows updates... but if you believe it is a good idea to format the hard drives and do a fresh install - then that is probably the best route.

Comment: should I use diskpart to format the hard drive, or let the Windows installer do it for me?  what would you suggest?